# Are homeopathy treated patients really experiencing "Placebo"?

Tags: practice-of-medicine

Today my mother told that a person who has heart disease is sound with an expensive homeopathic treatment. And I stopped explaining her that it's a placebo. I hear this claim a lot. In fact it worked for me!

[Kurzgesagt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HslUzw35mc) talks about homeopathy, and says it doesn't work properly.

[HRI says](https://www.hri-research.org/resources/homeopathy-faqs/the-best-studies-have-shown-homeopathy-is-just-placebo/) that homeopathy works for animals, who don't know what's placebo!

I once asked my homeopathy doctor that if it does do any harm. He said that yes, something that can cure a disease does do a lot of damage if overdosed. He also said that just the effect isn't as rapid as allopathy!

So let's reveal the truth. Is homeopathy really worth it?. What's homeopathy? Why placebo works for so many people? Does homeopathy really work?

Comment: Let's make sure we agree on what homeopathy is. I believe [this](http://www.1023.org.uk/what-is-homeopathy.php) to be an accurate description.

Comment: What's "the fruit of it?" Describe me the fruit in any measurable or other convincing way. What was the fruit of "expensive homeopathic treatment?"

Comment: Actually, even the administration of Open Label Placebo works in human. (https://journals.lww.com/pain/pages/articleviewer.aspx?year=2017&issue=12000&article=00007) In rats, Placebo has been able to substitute as immune suppressor, this is believed to be due to classic conditioning (Pavlov)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Homeopathy isn't a scientific thing, and sometimes it is very easily refuted
https://www.livescience.com/31977-homeopathy.html
homepathic "remedies" are compounds that are so diluted that there is a chance that the active molecule will appear only if the solution is as big as the solar system. There is no research that discovered how it works, so it is believed that it is a big fake and the only effect that it haves is the placebo.